# How to make a groovy @Deprecated property appears deprecated ('strikethrough') in Eclipse / IntelliJ?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am looking for a way to make IntelliJ (13-U EAP) or Eclipse (Kepler + Grails IDE 3.4) understands @Deprecated annotations on a domain class property, like :

```
@Resource
class Foobar {
  @Deprecated
  String someDeprecatedField
}
```

The code should appears like this (where the `<del>` parts should be <del>like this</del>) :

```
Foobar foobar = new Foobar(<del>someDeprecatedField</del>: 'a value')
foobar.<del>someDeprecatedField</del> = 'other value'
assert null != foobar.<del>someDeprecatedField</del>
```

Is there an option to make either Eclipse, either IntelliJ, understand that `@Deprecated` on a 'property' means deprecated on getter/setter ?

I know I can always create a getter, but if possible, I'd like to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Groovy-Eclipse:

[image: Groovy deprecated field]

Is this not what you are seeing?  I am using the latest dev snapshot of Groovy-Eclipse. What version are you seeing?

Pardon the green background, but I like to have different colors for each of my Eclipse workspaces.

Comment: Since I'm doing Grails, I'm using Grails IDE 3.4.0 (as a plugin).

Comment: That should include groovy-eclipse 2.8.0.  Do you not see the strikethroughs?

Comment: I guess that you took my example, but put all in the same file ? I tried, and yes, it work (Groovy Eclipse 2.9). However, what I did not say explicitly, is that the Foobar class is in grails-app/domains/, while the use of it is in grails-app/services. From what I understand of it, Eclipse works correctly in that case because it make a call to the field, and not the implicit getter/setter.